# Move constructor behaviour

Tags: c++, move-constructor

I recently stumbled upon some strange behaviour (strange from my point of view) from move constructor. The result is different when compiling with GCC and Visual Studio. I would like to hear the explanation of this behaviour, don't think this is a bug but probably compiler specific.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Test
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> v;
    std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator vend;

    Test(std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator &it)
        : vend { v.end() }
    {
        it = this->vend;
    };

    Test() = delete;
    Test(Test const &) = delete;
    Test(Test &&) = default; // <- line in question
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator it;
    std::unordered_map<int, Test> m;
    m.emplace(0, Test{ it });
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (m.at(0).v.end() == it) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

So I am storing iterator to the end of map in map element upon creation of the element. I also take a reference to it to compare later. From [std::unordered_map::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace):

> Inserts a new element into the container constructed in-place with the
>   given args if there is no element with the key in the container.
>
> Careful use of emplace allows the new element to be constructed while
>   avoiding unnecessary copy or move operations.

Using default move constructor, the iterator stored in map element and my reference are the same:

```
Test(Test &&) = default;
```

[Results](https://ideone.com/hhN1gX) are `true` in GCC and `true` in VS. Now if I change move constructor to:

```
Test(Test &&) {}
```

[GCC still returns](https://ideone.com/GZF5a3) `true` but VS returns `false`

Just in case tried with c++17, same results. So could anyone please explain what is happening here?

Comment: `Test{it}` as an out-parameter sets `it`.  The emplace does a move, which will invalidate the iterators.  The `m.at(0).v.end()` is being compared to the invalidated `it`.  Who knows what happens?  Make a wish.

Comment: @Eljay I was under impression that emplace does not move or copy, that it constructs element directly in the container

Comment: @Eljay Iterators inside a map would be preserved as the iterator that he is returning is of a map that is moved as well within the emplace....correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Kilzone, which constructor do you think it would use for the 'in place construction' in this case?

Comment: Instrument the various constructors and assignment operators with output so you can see which is happening in what order.  Won't be able to use the `default` implementation, but that should be okay for this experiment.

Comment: @MSSrikkanth • The `vend` iterator is for `v`, and `v` is in a valid but unspecified state (suitable only for destruction, or being assigned-to).

Comment: UPDATE: LWG 2321 ( §23.2.1 container.requirements.general /12) adds more information, but does say in many cases iterators are still valid... but not the `end()` iterator.  IANALL.

Comment: @Eljay - Associative containers Iterators don't get invalidated on a move and this includes the end Iterators as well.

Comment: Back to Killzone Kid's question, I do not know what `std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator` does for default construction as per the C++ standard.  It appears the one platform initializes it to the same as `end()` (or you just got lucky), and the other platform has it in an uninitialized state.  If you put in a `: vend{std::move(rhs.vend)}` you may get more consistent results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
m.emplace(0, Test{ it });
```

... the newly inserted `Test` object is constructed from `std::forward<Test>(Test{ it })`, so the move constructor is indeed called (because of the forwarding, copy elision does not work here). If you want to construct `Test` directly, you can use `m.emplace(0, it)` instead.

Now we can see

- With `Test(Test &&) = default;`, the temporary object designated by `Test{ it }.v` is moved into `m.at(0).v`. If `it` remains valid ([this is not guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map#Notes)), `m.at(0).v.end() == it` evaluates to `true`; otherwise the program results in undefined behavior.
- With `Test(Test &&) {}`, `m.at(0).v` is value-initialized, and `it` is invalidated as the temporary object designated by `Test{ it }.v` is destroyed. The program results in undefined behavior.

In libstdc++'s implementation, the end iterators for different `unordered_map`s have the same value (similar to `std::istream_iterator`),  so the behavior of GCC is reasonable.

Comment: This is good explanation and `m.emplace(0, it)` works nicely, though how does one avoid temporary if there more arguments than one in Test constructor? `m.emplace(0, it, somethingelse)`?

Comment: @KillzoneKid You can try `m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(0), std::forward_as_tuple(it, somethingelse))`.

Comment: Splendid, exactly what I needed!